# Создать объект в generic методе без использования рефлексии

Tags: java, объекты, generics

Есть метод:

```
public <T extends Animal> T createInstance(Class<T> clazz) {
     if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(Animal.class)) {
        if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(Dog.class)) {

           return ...;
        }
}
```

Находил много примеров с использованием метода `newInstance()`. А использовать его в данном случаи нельзя. Существуют ли другие способы создания объекта в рамках данного метода?

Comment: а [`Class::getConstructor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)) можно? И с чем связаны такие ограничения?

Answer (score 1):

Если запрет стоит на метод newInstance() (а это странно), то можно использовать метод getDeclaredConstructor(args) и создать класс с помощью него.
Без рефлексии вижу только один выход. Проверять в if на isAssignableFrom() для каждого вида классов и создавать их через new. Но зачем?

Comment: не обязательно брать `getDeclaredConstructor` можно сразу `getConstructors` а потом `setAccessible(true)`

Comment: Вот вариант c if и созданием через new я как раз и пытался осуществить. Но появилась проблема с new(скорее я не правильно искал). Был бы очень благодарен, если показали примером как создавать через оператор new в случаи данного метода.

Comment: Какой смысл так делать?

Comment: Научиться работать без рекурсии(хоть в этом случаи она бы не помешала)

Comment: если работать без рефлексии(я думаю Вы это имели в виду под рекурсией), то этот метод не нужен. Просто вызывайте new Dog() там где вы дёргаете этот метод, передавая Dog.class. Но раз Вы так просите:
public <T extends Animal> T createInstance(Class<T> clazz) {
     if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(Animal.class)) {
        if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(Dog.class)) {
           return (T) new Dog();
        }
} и т.д. Но я бы на Вашем месте пересмотрел архитектуру.